# iFrame content doesn't always open in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I have the following setup which works in a very odd way.

```
<a rel="nofollow"  href="<?=$r['link'];?>" target="mframe"><span class="cBlue">Title</span></a>
```

There are three links for instance

```
            <iframe
                name="mframe"
                width="1030"
                height="700"
                src="#"
                frameborder="yes"
                scrolling="yes">
            </iframe>
```

The strange problem that I'm experiencing is that once i click the first link, then second then third everything works fine, but when I click any of the links again it opens the linked page in the _parent window. I want it to be in the iFrame all the time no matter how many times i click on any of the links. Any suggestions?

Using OSX Chrome

Comment: You shouldn't use iframes, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in the iframe link target specify _self .

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I've noticed that it happens on the third time I click on any of the links.